# Convert $ajax to $http for angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, api

I hope following code to angularjs. Following code is using $ajax. How can I convert $ajax to $http for angularjs?

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsfiddle.net/',
        method: 'HEAD',
        start_time: new Date().getTime(),
        success: function(data) {
            alert('This request took '+(new Date().getTime() - this.start_time)+' ms');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well, by reading [the docs](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp) of course, where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Please focus `start_time`

Comment: and why that is problem? store it in local variable or in config if u want to use it in interceptor

Comment: I am going to use this function every 1 second. I am worried to change it if save in local variable